# node-formidable slugify filename

Tags: node.js, formidable

I'm stuck with slugifying filenames using node-formidable. I tried form.on but it already returns unpopular � replacement character. So filename 'ěščř.png' becomes '����.png' instead of escr.png

```
form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
    var new_location = 's:/localhost/nodejs/';      
    for(var i = 0; i < this.openedFiles.length; i++){
        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[i].path;
        var file_name = slug(this.openedFiles[i].name);
        fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {  
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);}
                    else {
                            console.log("success!")
                    }
                });
    }     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing code for 'slug' function, so i'm providing new slugify function.
'openedFiles' is also not given on your code, i am assuming all other things are ok.

On the top of your core require

const path = require('path');
Use This code

```
form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
    var new_location = 's:/localhost/nodejs/';      
    for(var i = 0; i < this.openedFiles.length; i++){
        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[i].path;

        var baseName = path.basename(this.openedFiles[i].name);
        var extName = path.extname(this.openedFiles[i].name);
        var file_name = slugify(baseName) + '.' + extName;
        fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {  
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);}
            else {
                    console.log("success!")
            }
        });
    }     
});

function slugify(text){
  return text.toString().toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
    .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
    .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
}
```